# Sticky footer doesn't work with Angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular

Here is my Angular project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1g7bvn

I've tried getting the sticky footer from [this example](https://codepen.io/dezertdezine/pen/zKjggy) to work with no avail:

```
html {
    height: 100%;  
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;    
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: yellowgreen;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background: papayawhip;
}

footer{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: gray; 
}
```

There must be something small I'm doing wrong but I can't see it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odw4hk cause by my-app wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is rendering your components as tags, so in your case `my-app` component is an actual tag on the DOM tree.

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <header></header>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

And all of your styles are applied to the `body` tag. If you add to your `app.component.css` your styles from `body` with a `:host` selector - it will work just fine.

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;    
  margin: 0;
}
```

here's a [stackblitzz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ydp86) example

Answer (score 0):

**Add below to your `CSS`.**

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0; 
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-angular-fixed-footer?file=src/app/app.component.html)**